# Count number of times a char has appeared in Tables that has occurred less than a number of times

Tags: sql

I'm trying to replicate this table:

[image: Expected Result Table]

which is to list all the names of the cities that have less than 2 manufacturer factories. I've tried to implement these methods through the use of HAVING(*) and mixing it with INNER JOIN, but I'm not exactly sure If I'm on the right track.

I have tried to code in 2 different ways through looking to other questions on stack:

1.

```
SELECT c.CityName as "City Name", m.CityID as "Number of Manufacturers"
FROM CITY4787 c 
INNER JOIN MANUFACTURER4787 m 
ON c.CityID = m.CityID
WHERE m.ManName IN (SELECT m.ManName FROM MANUFACTURER4787
GROUP BY m.ManID HAVING COUNT (ManID) > 2);
```

[image: Result Attempt 1]

The results aren't accurate but if I change the (ManID) to less than 2, there won't be any results.

2.

```
 SELECT CityID, COUNT(CityID) Counts
  FROM MANUFACTURER4787 
 GROUP BY CityID
HAVING COUNT(CityID) < 2;
```

[image: Result Attempt 2]

The result manages to count cityids that have appeared less than 2 but it is still not right.

I don't really understand how to merge the two or if im using these sql statements right. Here is the ERD : [ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmtDo.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I unserstand correct.you can try this.

If that doesn't spot you expect,Could you provide some sample data I will edit my answer.

```
SELECT c.CityName as "City Name", COUNT(m.ManID) as "Number of Manufacturers"
FROM CITY4787 c 
LEFT JOIN MANUFACTURER4787 m ON c.CityID = m.CityID
GROUP BY c.CityName
HAVING COUNT(m.ManID) < 2
```

Comment: Both answers has helped me greatly, the only parts i needed to change was from Inner Join to Left Join to show the 0 values, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your schema, I think this should work:

```
SELECT c.CityName as "City Name", COUNT(m.ManName) AS "Number of Manufacturers"
FROM City c
LEFT JOIN Manufacturer m
ON m.CityID = c.CityID
GROUP BY c.CityID
HAVING COUNT(m.ManName) < 2
```

Comment: Both answers has helped me greatly, the only parts i needed to change was from Inner Join to Left Join to show the 0 values, thank you very much! :)